# How to display date and time inside a form #markup?

Tags: 7, forms, i18n-l10n, datetime

I want to retrive a UNIX epoch (as returned by the PHP function `time()`) and display it as a formatted date as part of a text (i.e. a `#markup` element) in a form.  This is not a field where the user is supposed to enter a date. It is just showing the current date and time in a human readable format inside the form.

Is know that I can get a human readable date and time from a Unix epoch with the PHP `date()` function.

However, I am looking for the "Drupal" way of doing this. I think this means that I should display the date and time in the *short format* set by the site manager under *Home » Administration » Configuration » Regional and language*.

Is there a way to do this (or is there another way that is condidered "the Drupal way")?

**Edit:** Function `format_date()`  turned out to be the right answer.  It depends on a set of format variables (e.g. `date_format_short`) being set.  If this variable is undefined, you only get the US-centric formats hard-coded into `format_date()`.  The confusing bit is that when you visit the  *Home » Administration » Configuration » Regional and language* admin page, it shows you some formats (and I therefore errenously assumed that these formats were those that were defined for the site). But these formats are *not* defined until you press *Save configuration* on that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use the [`format_date()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/7) function.

```
$now = time();
$date = format_date($now, 'short');
```

You can use it with any of the date formats that are defined in your system, or you can pass in a custom [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) string.

Comment: Not sure why that doesn't work; I'm nearly positive I have done this on other sites before.  Double check the value of the `date_format_short` variable and make sure it matches what you think it should be.  You can also make a new date type from admin/config/regional/date-time and use that.  If you hover over the DELETE link, you will see the machine name to use.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed.